# Trying to update the httpd version on AWS Linux - Yum says no update?

Tags: apache-2.4

Im trying to upgrade the httpd version on my amazon EC2 instance because our security team asked me to do so.

Can anyone advise the easiest way to upgrade the httpd module?

I was told I needed to upgrade from this 2.4.48 to 2.4.56

```
[root@ip-172-X ec2-user]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.48 ()
Server built:   Jun 25 2021 18:53:37
[root@ip-172-X ec2-user]# sudo yum update httpd
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, update-motd
No packages marked for update
[root@ip-172-X ec2-user]#
```

But yum says no updates available?

If I try to do `yum install httpd` it goes back to 2.3.34?

Comment: The two CVE's are


https://alas.aws.amazon.com/cve/html/CVE-2023-25690.html

https://alas.aws.amazon.com/cve/html/CVE-2023-27522.html

But I don't know how to see if they are fixed?

Comment: Note that, depending on exactly which Amazon Linux version you're running the upgrade instructions differ. For example [CVE-2023-25690](https://alas.aws.amazon.com/cve/html/CVE-2023-25690.html) also includes [*"Run `dnf update --releasever=2023.0.20230322 httpd` to update your system."*](https://alas.aws.amazon.com/AL2023/ALAS-2023-136.html) resp. [*"Run `yum update httpd24` to update your system."*](https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ALAS-2023-1711.html)  in addition to the amazon Linux 2 instruction `yum upgrade httpd`

Answer (score 1):

There is no package with newer version in Amazon repo. You should wait for this. And ask your security team to check if the particular security issue exist in Amazon version of `httpd`.
You can try to clear the `yum` cache and check if you will find the package:

```
yum clean all
yum search httpd
```

Comment: So you mean I shouldn't try to upgrade?

Why does the amazon version say 2.4.34 is their latest?

Comment: @eezetee, you should update **when** the package is available in Amazon repo. Why this is the last  version you should ask Amazon.

Comment: Thanks Romeo


The two CVE's are alas.aws.amazon.com/cve/html/CVE-2023-25690.html alas.aws.amazon.com/cve/html/CVE-2023-27522.html But I don't know how to see if they are fixed?

Comment: @eezetee, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to ask two questions:

1. **Why is an upgrade required?**

   The  fairly typical response will come from your enterprise security team and often boils down to:

   > Our tooling detected that your system is vulnerable to one or more known vulnerabilities, including CVE numbers X, Y and Z and the vendor recommendation(s) to address that vulnerability states:

   > > *Users are recommended to **upgrade to version `[latest-version]`**, which fixes the issue.
   > >
   > > <sub>As for example seen in the recommendations on https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html</sub>*

   That is often not the best remediation.
2. Followed **How did you determine that my system is vulnerable?**
   The response from the security team is rarely:

   > We performed a penetration test and were successful in exploiting CVE-2023-X, CVE 2023-Y etc.

   And much more commonly:

   > Your vulnerable application advertises a version number  `X.Y.Z` and our tooling did a version lookup in a database like: [cvedetails.com -> Apache -> HTTPD](https://www.cvedetails.com/version-list/45/66/1/Apache-Http-Server.html)  and found one or more vulnerabilities for that version.

   This second method is often a cause of false positives.

---

If you're actually vulnerable and how to address that depends on **which Linux distribution** and **what version** your system is on and **how the vulnerable software was installed**:

- When your vulnerable software was **compiled from source** by yourself, then typically your system will be running exactly the version that it advertises and **your system will be vulnerable**.
  You will need to download the latest upstream release, recompile, test and deploy. Also consider subscribing to the upstream mailing list so you'll be notified about new releases and can respond much more timely in the future.

  Determine which packages are installed with the package manager or not use  for example `apt list --installed` resp. `yum list installed`, or use something like `rpm -qf /usr/sbin/httpd` or `dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/adduser` to find if the vulnerable programme is owned by a package or not.
- When you're on a Linux distribution that **[backports security updates](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting)**, there is no **no direct correlation** between the reported **version number and patch status**. This frequently causes false positives.

  [This explanation](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) is from Red Hat but the effects with regards the security updates in Ubuntu (LTS) releases, (Open) SUSE and [Amazon Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/) (not for all packages though) are the roughly the same. Applying security updates will address vulnerabilities without updating the software version.

  Assuming that the software is a standard component of your enterprise Linux distribution, that the distribution is still supported and (security) updates have not been disabled, then **applying normal updates is sufficient to keep your system secure**. The distribution will have assessed each new CVE, determined if the version they ship is actually effected, if necessary backport the upstream versions fix and will (eventually) have released a security update.

  Determine your Linux distribution / release with for example `hostnamectl` and/or `lsb_release -a` or the checking `/etc/*-release` files.

  Confirm (security) update repo's are enabled with for example: `yum repolist` or `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

  To state the obvious: when a system is no longer supported you won't receive any security updates fro the vendor anymore.

  You may need to check the distribution specific security database (for example https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/cve https://ubuntu.com/security/cves https://www.suse.com/security/cve/ https://alas.aws.amazon.com/ ) if a CVE effects your system and if an update was released. (There are better distribution specific (command line) tools to perform such searches / make such reports. )

  Determine the patch version (release) of the (rpm/deb) package (`rpm -qi httpd` or `apt show apache2`) rather than the version number the software reports (`/sbin/httpd -v`) to see if your system has been updated correctly or still needs updating.

  Use for example `rpm -q --changelog httpd` or `apt-get changelog apache2` to report which CVE's have been fixed in particular installed package when you need to convince the security department that your system is not vulnerable.

Comment: Great info. I'll go thru this and see what I can do.  Right now it shows no amazon linux update available and their latest is 2.4.34 whereas i'm at 2.4.48 already. 

That said, if indeed the security team did just do a version crawl and reporting that i'm vulnerable, if my version is indeed 2.4.48 then it would see I am.  The reason I say this is because if Amazon is 2.4.34 and I am 2.4.48 then it must have come in the first install I did.